# ssh 2fa not working but works when i sudo

Tags: ssh, authentication

I have a problem with the 2FA enabled on my linux.. I made all the required things that are needed to enable the 2FA but i 2FA is not working when i want to connect to the linux OS with ssh. I made the connection with public/private key but the verification with google authentication is not working..

It works when i go and i connect to the PC directly after inserting the password it shows the verification code but when i connect with ssh it does not show the verification code.. After i connect with the private key when i want to execute something with super user privileges it works ( i mean it requires from me to insert the time based code generated in my app).

My question is how to enable the 2FA when i connect to the PC with ssh and private/public key?
I mean when i try to login i want to 2FA to show and the be the second security step on my PC. Thank you very much

The linux i use is Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: it is ubuntu 24.04. I guess because the guide was from 2021 something is not working..

Comment: i am sorry it is Ubuntu 22.04.. misclicked when was writing it.. sorry again..

Comment: i guess i have all the needed info.. can we please try to solve my problem?

Comment: Please include *all* relevant parts of the configuration. You have *no* technical information about your configuration, and no log or error messages.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my issue. I guess others have this problem also..

Had to add some extra lines to the sshd and sshd_config files to make ssh aware of mfa..

in the file /etc/ssh/sshd_config in the end i had to add auth methods:

```
AuthenticationMethods publickey,password publickey,keyboard-interactive
```

Than in the /etc/pam.d/sshd had to comment out the:

```
@include common-auth

sudo systemctl restart sshd.service
```

And in the end restart the service and it worked!